# how to sub regex for return of function using found regex as argument

Tags: python

I have a string containing several matches to a regex and I want to replace them using a function:

```
string = '''
{
  "database": {
    "writer": {
      "url": "mysql://app:$(secret/vault/path#password)@mysql_host:3306/db?read_timeout=30",
      "connect_args": {
        "ssl": {
          "ca": "/etc/certs/private-ca-cert.pem"
         }
      }
    },
    "reader": {
      "url": "mysql://app:$(secret/vault/path#password)@other_host:3306/db?read_timeout=30",
      "connect_args": {
        "ssl": {
          "ca": "/etc/certs/private-ca-cert.pem"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
'''
def parser_function(path):
    # code to parse the path and render secret
    ...

regex = re.compile(r'\$\(.+?\)')
regex.sub(parser_function(<path from regex>), string)
```

Is there a way to pass the `<path from regex>` as an argument? eg `parser_function('secret/vault/path#password')`?

I'm having trouble figuring out how to both replace regex inline and also have the captured regex to use. `findall` won't work I don't think because I need to sub the regex in the context of the string.

Comment: Regarding the downvoting of this question, I don't believe it's relevant to vote down something in which you have no context. Of course if I could do this in a more structured way I would choose the more structured way. This involves a lot of moving parts and variables inside kubernetes and to structure everything coming in to the kustomize generator that I'm writing would be overly strict and limiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a function as an argument to `re.sub`. The specified function would be invoked for each match, but the argument would be the `re.Match` object. So you can do something like the following

```
def parser_function(match):
    path = match.group(0)
    # code to parse the path and render secret
    ...

regex = re.compile(r'\$\(.+?\)')
regex.sub(parser_function, string)
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how this is working, but it does seem to work! There's an implicit argument being passed in `sub` to `parser_function`?